# Change .CSS() when .SlideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I did an accordion with jQuery and have the problem now, that an icon should change back, when the content slides up. For other accordions it works fine, but actually I have no idea how to realize it for the active accordion (if you click again on the accordion, you opened just before). The icon rotates with `transform:rotate(90deg)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".preview").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".accordion-invisible").slideToggle(200);
        $(".accordion .accordion-invisible").not($(this).next()).slideUp(200);

        $('span').css({
            transform: 'rotate(0deg)', 
            bottom: '0px'
        });

        $(this).find("span").css({
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
        });

        $(this).parents(".accordion").find("span").css({
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)', 
            bottom: '10px'
        });
    });
});
```

I put my whole code into CodePen: [You can find it here](http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/GoPdgZ) Has somebody any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the logic in the `click` binding a bit.

You could **add** a helper `class` (lets say `.active`) to the currently active accordion. If the clicked element has the class `.active` you'll know to close it. Else check if another `slide` has `.active`, close that one and open the clicked one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".preview").click(function(){
        var $this = $( this );

        if ($this.hasClass("active")) {
        // the "clicked" element is already opened
        // --> we just need to close it

            $this.removeClass("active");
            $this.parents(".accordion").find("span").css({transform:"rotate(0deg)", bottom:"0px"});
            $this.next(".accordion-invisible").slideUp(200);

        } else {
        // the "clicked" element is not showing

            var $currentActive = $(".preview.active");
            if ($currentActive.length) {
            // another element is opened
            // we need to close it first

                $currentActive.parents(".accordion").find("span").css({transform:"rotate(0deg)", bottom:"0px"});
                $currentActive.next(".accordion-invisible").slideUp(200);
                $currentActive.removeClass("active");

            }

            $this.next(".accordion-invisible").slideDown(200);
            $this.parents(".accordion").find("span").css({transform:"rotate(90deg)", bottom:"10px"});
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a Pen](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/wMRjyP)

Answer (score 0):

jquery SlideToggle function has a [callback](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) as second argument

```
$('foo').slideToggle( 200 , function() {
 //do something with span rotation ...
})
```

Perhaps, you need try use Classes and CSS transitions for this. For example set active class for current slide. And then use nested selector for span;

`(.active span {transform: rotate(90deg)})`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a callback function in `slideToggle` and do what you want in that function, after your `slideToggle` finishes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".preview").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".accordion-invisible").slideToggle(200);
        //PUT CALL FUNCTION IN FOLLOWING LINE
        $(".accordion .accordion-invisible").not($(this).next()).slideUp(200,function(){

        $('span').css({
            transform: 'rotate(0deg)', 
            bottom: '0px'
        });

        $(this).find("span").css({
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
        });

        $(this).parents(".accordion").find("span").css({
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)', 
            bottom: '10px'
        });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For toggling such accordions I use the jQuery toggle() function. You don't need to slideUp and slideDown, toggle is enough. Here is the code, also for the arrows.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".preview").click(function() {
        var acc = $(this).next(".accordion-invisible");
        acc.toggle(200, function() {
            if (acc.is(':visible')) {
                acc.parent().find('.fa').css({
                    transform:'rotate(90deg)'
                });
            } else {
                acc.parent().find('.fa').css({
                    transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
```

if the accordion is visible, rotate the arrow 90deg, else, rotate 0deg.
Check the codepen for a working example: http://codepen.io/LevelZwo/pen/jWXKOX?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) do that with a lot less code.  Here's an example that uses pure CSS for the transitions; javascript is used only to toggle a classname on and off:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.preview').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.accordion').toggleClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.preview {
  cursor: pointer /* always indicate when something is clickable */
}
.accordion-invisible,
.accordion span.fa {
  transition: all 1s; /* add  browser prefixes as necessary */
}
.accordion-invisible {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.accordion.active .accordion-invisible {
  max-height: 500px; /* pick something reasonable for your content */
}
.accordion.active span.fa {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="accordion">
  <h2><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>Hallöchen Popöchen</h2>
  <p class="preview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  <div class="accordion-invisible">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <h2><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>Blindtext</h2>
  <p class="preview">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <div class="accordion-invisible">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```